# I am writing an Android app in java with what I believe to be a memory leak and don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am writing a java app for a school project where there are several card games. I am writing the first one and have implemented a skeleton for all the games I plan to do. I have a class called Deck that controls all of the card deck logic and creates a deck with 52 card objects in an arrayList. Whenever I create a card deck, the program stops and doesn't respond. As far as I have looked online, it says that I am creating too many objects and the program tries to clean them up or something. I am fairly new to java and am very confused at how to fix this problem. Here is the createDeck() method and resulting LogCat output. Any help or wisdom is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
public void createDeck() 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
        {

            if (j == 0) //If diamond suite
            {
                Card newCard = new Card(i, j);
                cardDeck.add(newCard);
            }

            if (j == 1) //If hearts suite
            {
                Card newCard = new Card(i, j);
                cardDeck.add(newCard);
            }

            if (j == 2) //If clover suite
            {
                Card newCard = new Card(i, j);
                cardDeck.add(newCard);
            }

            if (j == 3) //If spade suite
            {
                Card newCard = new Card(i, j);
                cardDeck.add(newCard);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

LogCat output

```
WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 61ms
GC_CONCURRENT freed 153K, 7% free 3755K/4024K, paused 69ms+25ms total 213ms
```

Comment: Do you intend to add to separate deck for each different value of `j`?

Comment: This method only creates the cards that are located in the deck.

Answer (score 4):

A tiny bug:

In the second `for` loop change:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)
```

to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

By the way, by using a debugger or printing to log - you'd find it in a second.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Sometimes it takes a second person to point out the obvious. That fixed the problem. Thank you!